# Override WndProc

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, wndproc

i'm developing an Outlook Add-In with C#, VS 2010 and Outlook 2010. 
I have written a Programm in an Adjoining Form (it is be shown on the bottom of a Outlook Mail).

Now my problem is, that on each "Tab Press" for example, the focus jump out of the AddIn Form to Outlook. I have some Text Boxes and so on, who should focused by tab pressing.

Now is my solution approach to override the WndProc and send all Messages to my custom form, but I don't know how to do this ? 
Have anyone an example how to to it or a better way how I can solve the problem ?

With best Regards and thanks for your answers

Bilib

Comment: That cannot be done by WndProc, it must be done by the message loop.  Which is the problem, it is Outlook's message loop that intercepts the keystroke.  Tabbing can only work properly if you display the form with ShowDialog().